# getting error : accessing '/1.1/statuses/sample.json?stall_warnings=true'. Reason: Please use V2 filtered and sample volume stream as alternatives

Tags: real-time-data, flume-twitter

Problem accessing '/1.1/statuses/sample.json?stall_warnings=true'. Reason:   Please use V2 filtered and sample volume stream as alternatives.

can anyone help me to get out from these? what will be the changes in configuration?

Comment: I'll assume you are using the Twitter API. The error tells you to use Twitter API v2.0 https://developer.twitter.com/en/support/twitter-api/v2 In any case, can you add more details to your question? e.g. what are you trying to do and how

Comment: Thankyou !!
I want to ingest twitter data in hdfs.when I was run twitter conf file it shows mentioned error.
ERROR org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource - Exception while streaming tweets
twitter4j.TwitterException: 403:The request is understood, but it has been refused. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits (https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following).
Error 403  : Please use V2 filtered and sample volume stream as alternatives